# How do you create a table that is named after a student id using jpa?

Tags: java, sql, spring-mvc, jpa, h2

I am trying to create a student grade application where I am creating a table after each student, an naming it their student Id. The problem is whenever I create a student, it says that there is an expected "identifier", which I searched, but it doesn't seem to be the problem.

I tried using jpql instead of using a native query, but it gave me the same result. I changed around the sql statement, and even added a primary key, but the problem is that I still get the same error.

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "CREATE TABLE ? ( AssignmentId int, ClassId int, Grade int, total int);", nativeQuery = true)
public void gradeCreator(String Id);
```

And use that method when the student is created

```
int i = s.getId();
String x = Integer.toString(i);
StudentDao.gradeCreator(x);
```

The expected result would be a new sql table, named after the student Id, such as 100, but I only get the error stated above. Thanks in regards.

Comment: Why would create a table per student? Why not just have a column for the student id? Seems a maintenance nightmare to have a variable numbers of tables based on student numbers.

Comment: That's because I have to add assignments and give a grade for them, and they have to be there for each student.

Comment: Sounds like you need to take a class in database design, because you almost never create new dynamic tables at runtime. You especially don't do that if you use JPA, since JPA is an object-relational mapping API, which needs a well-defined database model.

Comment: Yeah, but in a proper normalised database you have a student table, which contains a *record* (not a table) per student. Then in your assignment table you have a foreign key relationship back to your student table, i.e. each row in your assignment table belongs to a single student.

Comment: @NicholasBegg As Dale Burrell said, you add a student id column to your grade table, so you can query the grade records pertinent to a particular student. You don't create a new grade table for each student.

Comment: OK. Makes sense. But what do I do if there is multiple assignments for a student with one id? Would I have to do a one to many mapping?